# Performance tune getting Max Value's details

Tags: sql-server, max, query-performance

I have a scenario where I need to get the Max date record's FXRate for the combination of FromCountry and ToCountry.

```
    FromCountry    ToCountry      FXRate         FXDate
   --------------------------------------------------------
    A               B             1.14           1/1/2019
    A               B             1.13           2/1/2019
    A               B             1.12           3/1/2019
    A               B             1.11           4/1/2019 -- Expected Record for 'A' and 'B'
    c               D             1.16           1/1/2019
    c               D             1.17           2/1/2019
    c               D             1.18           3/1/2019
    c               D             1.19           4/1/2019 -- Expected Record for 'C' and 'D'
```

The issue is the view 'FXView' is having many records and my current approach looks something like this

```
SELECT
       fx.FromCountry
     , fx.ToCountry
     , fx.FXDate
     , fx.FXRate
FROM
(
SELECT
        FromCountry
      , Tocountry
      , Max(FXDate) as MaxFXDate 
FROM FXView
GROUP BY 
        FromCountry
      , Tocountry
)result
INNER JOIN FXView fx
   ON   result.FromCountry = fx.FromCountry
   AND  result.ToCountry   = fx.ToCountry
   AND  result.MaxFXDate   = fx.FXDate
```

I tried using the Max window function as well and then getting the 'distinct' of it but that takes time as well.

Is there any better solution to this performance wise?

Note: This view does not have any natural key in it.

Comment: what is table structure and are there any indexes on in?

Comment: It is actually a view not a table, it has only these 4 columns.

Comment: please provide underlying tables and indexes on tables and definition of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try common table expression like as follows, in some cases it helps to improve the performance

```
WITH result(FromCountry,ToCountry, MaxFXDate) AS(
SELECT
        FromCountry
      , Tocountry
      , Max(FXDate) as MaxFXDate 
FROM FXView
GROUP BY 
        FromCountry
      , Tocountry
)

SELECT
       fx.FromCountry
     , fx.ToCountry
     , fx.FXDate
     , fx.FXRate
FROM
result
INNER JOIN FXView fx
   ON   result.FromCountry = fx.FromCountry
   AND  result.ToCountry   = fx.ToCountry
   AND  result.MaxFXDate   = fx.FXDate
```

Comment: Tried this one, its taking the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Does it even need a group by, or a join?

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
   fx.FromCountry
 , fx.ToCountry
 , fx.FXDate
 , fx.FXRate
FROM FXView fx
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fx.FromCountry, fx.ToCountry ORDER BY fx.FXDate DESC)
```

Comment: Will this not give me the just top 1 of the entire result. Anyhow this is not giving me the expected records.

Comment: Not of the entire result, but the top 1 for each country pair sorted by the date.